# Get CoordinatorLayout Behavior in Constructor of Custom View

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have created a custom view to handle my bottom sheet implementation. I have tried to retrieve the bottomsheet behavior using `BottomSheetBehavior.from( this )` but since I need the behavior in the constructor, `this` is not yet initalized.

For now, I've managed a workaround using postDelayed runnable at 1ms to get the behavior and do what I need but that is clearly a hack.

I have been unable to find any other ways to get the behavior.

[EDIT]

After looking a bit deeper, `this` not being initialized does not seem to be the problem. The problem is that the `LayoutParams` are not an instance of `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` when `BottomSheetBehavior.from` is called directly from the constructor but they are `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` when called from the runnable created in the constructor.

Comment: have you tried using the `view.post(Runnable)` method?? This will get executed once the view pending task are completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the View documentation a bit more, I moved the calls from the view's constructor to its onAttachedToWindow method.

I find this to be much cleaner than using a runnable.